# SQL grouped statement with count and percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a table(simplified) like so

```
ID1  ID2  Status
---  ---  ------
1    33     0 
1    33     0 
1    33     1 
1    33     1 
1    34     1 
1    34     2 
2    33     0
2    33     0
2    34     0
```

I want to get a count the total number of statuses grouped by the status type and also its percentage to the number of statuses pertaining to the particular IDs ID1 & ID2

An example output would be

```
ID1  ID2  Status   Count   Percentage
---  ---  ------   -----   ----------
1    33     0        2         50%
1    33     1        2         50%
1    34     1        1         50%
1    34     2        1         50%
2    33     0        2         100%
2    34     0        1         100%
```

So far I have only been able to get the count, but not the percentage. This is my query now

```
select ID1, ID2 ,  status, count(ID2) as Count 
 from 
StatTable
 group by ID1, ID2, status
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the percentage by using window functions to get the total for each `id1`, `id2` combination:

```
select ID1, ID2 ,  status, count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 100.0 / count(*) over (partition by id1, id2) as Percentage
from StatTable
group by ID1, ID2, status;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what do you mean by window functions ? I am getting wrong percentage values.

Comment: I am trying to work the SUM into the percentage calculation. for the first four records in my table, I have 2 with status =0 and 2 with status = 1. So a total of 4. Therefore count(cnt) * 100 / SUM(ID2)... something like that?

Comment: @user20358 . . . No.  You seem to want to divide the count for `id1,id2,status` by the count for `id1,id2` according to the data in your question.  Using `sum()` on something called an `id` seems like a bad idea.  The documentation for window functions (which use the `over` clause) is here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake.. I meant something like count(ID2) * 100 / SUM(cnt)... I know this doesnt work like this in sql.  Currently I am able to get the percentages using a subquery, but wasnt sure if that was the best way. Its very similar to what you have done except for the part where I replace the "count(*) over (partition by id1, id2)" with a "select count(ID2) from stattable group by ID1"

Comment: still not sure if the way I have done is a good way. Apologies for the confusion earlier...

Comment: @user20358 . . . As you already know, you cannot use a column alias at the same level of a select.  So what you want to do is not possible.  The easiest solution is to use `window` functions (any other solutions require subqueries or joins).

Comment: Thanks. Up voted your answer for the hint I used to get mine & also for mentioning window functions. Perhaps I can use it somewhere else when I understand it better..

Answer (score 0):

I made minor changes to Gordon query and now its matching with your expected answer -

```
select ID1, ID2 ,  status, count(*) as cnt,
       100.0 / count(*) over (partition by id1, id2) as Percentage
from table1TEmp
group by ID1, ID2, status;
```

Comment: remove the count(*) * before 100.0 from gordon query and you will start getting correct answer. I tried in my machine with your example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
select ID1, ID2 ,  status, count(ID2) as cnt,
       count(ID2) * 100.0 / (select count(ID2) from StatTable group by ID1) as Percentage
from StatTable
group by ID1, ID2, status;
```